# wrapper for a function with variable arguments in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Recently I wanted to implement a `printf` wrapper. After some search I found the `vprintf` is good for this need:

```
void my_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

But is it possible to implement such a wrapper for `printf` or any other similar functions with variable arguments instead of `va_list`?

(I mean, what if they don't provide a `v` version?)

---

Since some commenter didn't fully capture my idea, I'd better elaborate it.

Suppose you have a plain `printf` function as in the C library.

Some one gives you a `fmt` string `"%d %u %f"`, and corresponding inputs.

Now you want to write a function similar to `printf`, but with all `%f` replaced by `%.2f`.

Of course you can use two statements to finish the task:

```
replace(fmt, "%f", "%.2f");
printf(fmt, inputs);
```

But if you use this function many times, probably you want to have a wrapper to save some time.

A macro can finish this task, of course. But is it possible without a macro, like:

```
void myprintf(fmt, ...)
{
    replace(fmt, "%f", "%.2f");
    printf(fmt, inputs);
}
```

The problem here is that you don't know how to feed the inner `printf` with the arguments `...` of `myprintf`.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I cannot understand what you really want. Do you want to have variables arguments without having to use `va_list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to use this to prepend an string to the output or so, you could use a variadic macro.

```
#define MYPRINT(...) printf("toto has: " __VA_ARGS__)
```

in that simple example this suppposes that format that you pass in is a string literal, so this is a bit restricted. But I hope you see the pattern how to use such simple macro wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to construct a call to a variadic function when the API don't offer you functions with `va_list` parameter.

However, you could [ab]use the [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) for that purpose, by constructing the variadic call and doing it.