# C wrapper macro to add extra arguments to function

Tags: c

I want a C macro that will expand into a function with an extra parameter based on a condition.

Something like this:

```
#define EXTRA 7
#ifdef ADD_ONE_MORE_ARG
#define dothis(...) dothat(EXTRA,...)
#endif
```

Such that `dothis(5);` is expanded into `dothat(EXTRA, 5);` but I can't remember the syntax. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954830/wrapper-for-a-function-with-variable-arguments-in-c) I found here didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979) what you're looking for?

Comment: Note that if `dothat` is a function with a fixed number of parameters (say 4), then you can write the macro as `#define dothis(x,y,z) dothat(EXTRA,(x),(y),(z))`

Comment: Didn't see a relevant answer there @user3386109 thanks. The other function does take a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define callx(...) call(EXTRA, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: And here's the documentation which has an example that covers exactly what I was after. Didn't read the right section at first! https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html